# iOS What should I call from the main thread when changing UI?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an extension for alert presentation. When `showAlert()` called not from the main thread, I get "changing UI not from the main thread" behaviour. Sometimes an alert not presented at all, sometimes with big delay. No crashes. But if I put all the function's code inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure - everything is fine. Why? Shouldn't I call from the main thread only the code that actually changes UI?

```
@objc extension UIAlertController {

static func showAlert(title: String?, message: String? = nil, closeActionTitle: String? = "OK", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, actions: [UIAlertAction]? = nil) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                                message: message,
                                                preferredStyle: preferredStyle)
        var allActions = [UIAlertAction]()
        if let closeTitle = closeActionTitle {
            allActions.append(UIAlertAction(title: closeTitle, style: .cancel))
        }
        allActions.append(contentsOf: actions ?? [])
        allActions.forEach { alertController.addAction($0) }

        let vc = ClearViewController()
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.backgroundColor = AppTheme.color.clear
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        vc.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, all UI changing operations should be done on the main thread only. 
If not, the system does not assure you when, in which order of even if the UI is going to be updated with your code.

Now, you are right to want to clutter the main thread as little as possible and put only the UI related code. But if you look closer at the lines you will notice these:

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window.rootViewController = vc
```

which are modifying the UI also but are outside of the main closure. 
I believe that if you move these 2 lines on the main thread, your warning will be gone!

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the current window or not, calling `window.makeKeyAndVisible()` will show it in front of the current window

Comment: I might be wrong but if I remember correctly, this is actually a trick given from one the developers at Apple a while ago during one of the WWDC sessions

Comment: That being said creating a new window will assure you that nothing will be show on top of your alert and you will always be the top most view. If this is not particularly important to you then I agree that it would maybe make more sense to present it on the current window as we already have one!

Comment: You said "If not, the system does not assure you when, in which order of even if the UI is going to be updated with your code." It's much more serious than that. The results are undefined, and range from your UI changes not happening at all, to long delays, to loss of data or **APP CRASHES**.

Comment: **DO NOT MAKE UKIT CALLS FROM A BACKGROUND THREAD, FULL STOP**

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `UIKit` is not thread-safe. You should make **ALL** calls to `UIKit`, including creating or setting properties on `UIKit` objects, from the main thread. There are a *few* minor exceptions to this, but only a few and they are usually well documented. Interacting with `UIKit` objects from the main thread is never bad, and interacting with `UIKit` objects from background threads is almost always bad. (Results of this are "undefined" and sometimes fatal.)

If you do **ALL** interaction with `UIKit` objects from the main thread you won't have any concurrency problems. Do your time-consuming networking and/or number crunching code in the background, and then wrap the code to present the results to the user in calls to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC, I think your message is pretty clear although the question was never "why should I make UI changes on main thread" but rather "what UI changes am I currently NOT making on UI thread". With this though I think nobody will ever dare make UI changes on background thread ;)

Comment: I answered that too: "You should make ALL calls to UIKit, including creating or setting properties on UIKit objects, from the main thread." You create and configure 4 or 5 UIKit objects outside of your call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are calling show alert method from background
So you are invoking main thread with this code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    vc.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

All UI changes should be in main thread.